# References in margins `biblatex`

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, margins

How can I use `biblatex` and not have the references run into the margins? I've seen some posts and solutions to this problem pertaining to URLs but I'm not using web links so it's a different problem. `biblatex` appears to not want to break the titles of books.

My `\usepackage` statement, if it helps, is as follows:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=authoryear,sorting=nyt,
   eprint=false,isbn=false,url=false,doi=false]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488975/35864

Answer (score 17):

It appears as though there is a conflict between the package `biblatex` and `ulem`. That is, `\usepackage[options]{biblatex}` and `\usepackage{ulem}` when used together not only result in underlined journal names but also citations that extend into the margins. Omitting `\usepackage{ulem}` or using `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}` fixed this problem and allowed `biblatex` to italicize journal names and wrap citations as expected.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a conflict, but of course this is a semantic discussion as the outcome is the same whether you call this a conflict or a limitation in one of the packages. Contrary to LaTeX's standard `\underline` `ulem`'s underlining macro allows its argument to line-break/hyphenate. This, however, only works if the argument is "nice enough" (basically raw text). In the context of `biblatex`, however, the argument to the command is not simply text, it is complex code that typesets text.  While this looks similar in many applications, it makes a difference here. ...

Comment: ... Which means that the underlining does not break.

Answer (score 7):

Linebreaks in `biblatex` are controlled by the parameters (counters) `abbrevpenalty`, `highnamepenalty` and `lownamepenalty`.

```
\bibsetup{
  \setcounter{abbrvpenalty}{0}
  \setcounter{highnamepenalty}{0}
  \setcounter{lownamepenalty}{0}
}
```

The above setting should permit linebreaks in names and abbreviations (e.g., et al)