# Title in the bibliography is crossing the margin

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, natbib

Some of the titles in the bibliography are crossing the margin and continuing without the line break. I have tried a lot of ways to correct it but can't understand what is wrong.[image: []

Comment: \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)


\makeindex
\addbibresource{thesis}      \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]  This is my code for the printing biblography

Comment: Please edit the question with the source for a minimal working example.  Anyway, it seems to me that the problem is the underlining. But, the underlining titles in not part of the normal styles. Please add the full information to replicate your problem.

Comment: Please edit that code into your question.  Underlining doesn't allow breaking very well; it's more usual to set titles in italic, which has no problems in that respect.  What document class is being used, and is underlining *required* by whomever is specifying the style?

Comment: Chances are you are loading the `ulem` package, which changes the default behaviour of `\emph` from italics to underlining. Unfortunately, the underlined text cannot break when it comes from `biblatex`. You probably don't want underlining here anyway, so load `ulem` with the `normalem` option: `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70851/35864.

Comment: Oh!!!! @moewe you are the savior of my thesis Thanks a lot it worked perfectly THANK YOU VERY MUCH.