# Bibliography exceeds line width

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, setspace

[image: screeshot of the references]
When printing the references some lines exceed the width of the page as shown in the attached screenshot, How to fix this problem?
the following code is used. Thanks for your help.

```
\begin{document}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} %title control and formatting
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} %table of contents control and formatting
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric-comp, bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}%sets the way your references come in and what citation style you are using
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,hidelinks]{hyperref}%for hyperlinking your toc and referenced figs and tabs

\begin{singlespace}  % use single-line spacing for multi-line text within a single reference
    \setlength\bibitemsep{\baselineskip}  %manually set separation between items in bibliography to double space
    \printbibliography[title={References}]

\end{singlespace}
```

---

```
@book{burckhardt1993fahrwerktechnik,
  title={Fahrwerktechnik: Radschlupf-Regelsysteme: Reifenverhalten, Zeitablaeufe, Messung des Drehzustands der Raeder, Anti-Blockier-System (ABS), Theorie Hydraulikkreislaeufe, Antriebs-Schlupf-Regelung (ASR), Theorie Hydraulikkreislaeufe, elektronische Regeleinheiten, Leistungsgrenzen, ausgefuehrte Anti-Blockier-Systeme und Antriebs-Schlupf-Regelungen},
  author={Burckhardt, Manfred},
  year={1993},
  publisher={Vogel}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would appear that your attempt to post a screenshot wasn't successful. Please give it another try.

Comment: We'll almost certainly need a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to be able to diagnose the problem; a small snippet of code isn't enough.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please post a short but complete code. Moreover, your screenshot is missing.

Comment: The screenshot appears to have gotten lost, so we can't say a lot. But generally, it is hard to say something useful aside from general remarks as discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/442308/35864 unless there is compilable code that lets us reproduce the undesirable line breaks in detail (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: From the screenshot I'm guessing you (or your template or class) are loading the `ulem` package. `ulem` will redefine `\emph` so that it gives underlined text. The command does not allow for line breaks when used in this context. Either don't load `ulem` at all or load it with `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70851/35864

Comment: Please also post the bib entry in question.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488975/35864