# IEEEtran: Underlined Bibliography text overflows column boundaries

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, ieeetran, ieee-style

I'm writing an article based on the [IEEE Transactions](https://template-selector.ieee.org/api/ieee-template-selector/template/62/download) template. However, I am using websites as sources, so I chose to use BibLaTeX and `biber` to compile my bibliography rather than BibTeX.

Originally, I was using BibTeX, and the compiled document turned out fine. When I changed to BibLaTeX, however, underlined portions of the bibliography flow over the column boundary and overlap with text in the other columns.

Here is my (example) document source:

```latex
                          %%%% Please compile with XeLaTeX and Biber. %%%%
\documentclass[letter,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=scriptsize]{subfig}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage{acronym,changepage,enumitem,xspace,seqsplit,siunitx,tabularx,ulem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor IEEE-Xplore}
% updated with editorial comments 8/9/2021
\graphicspath{{./figures/}}

\bibliography{./bibliography.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@Article{Aksoy2023,
    author      = {Aksoy, Levent and Nguyen, Quang-Linh and Almeida, Felipe and Raik, Jaan and Flottes, Marie-Lise and Dupuis, Sophie and Pagliarini, Samuel},
    date        = {2023-01-26},
    title       = {Hybrid Protection of Digital FIR Filters},
    doi         = {10.48550/ARXIV.2301.11115},
    eprint      = {2301.11115},
    eprintclass = {cs.CR},
    eprinttype  = {arXiv},
    copyright   = {Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International},
    file        = {:http\://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.11115v1:PDF},
    keywords    = {Cryptography and Security (cs.CR), Signal Processing (eess.SP), FOS: Computer and information sciences, FOS: Electrical engineering, electronic engineering, information engineering},
    publisher   = {arXiv},
    year        = {2023},
}

@Article{Chen2023,
    author      = {Chen, Xiaoyue and Aimoniotis, Pavlos and Kaxiras, Stefanos},
    date        = {2023-01-25},
    title       = {Clueless: A Tool Characterising Values Leaking as Addresses},
    doi         = {10.48550/ARXIV.2301.10618},
    eprint      = {2301.10618},
    eprintclass = {cs.CR},
    eprinttype  = {arXiv},
    copyright   = {Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike 4.0 International},
    file        = {:http\://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.10618v1:PDF},
    keywords    = {Cryptography and Security (cs.CR), Hardware Architecture (cs.AR), FOS: Computer and information sciences},
    publisher   = {arXiv},
    year        = {2023},
}

@Article{Denton2023,
    author      = {Denton, Peter B.},
    date        = {2023-01-23},
    title       = {Klein-Gordon Equation with Self-Interaction $λφ^4$ and Arbitrary Spherical Source Terms},
    doi         = {10.48550/ARXIV.2301.11106},
    eprint      = {2301.11106},
    eprintclass = {physics.comp-ph},
    eprinttype  = {arXiv},
    copyright   = {Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International},
    file        = {:http\://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.11106v1:PDF},
    keywords    = {Computational Physics (physics.comp-ph), High Energy Physics - Phenomenology (hep-ph), Classical Physics (physics.class-ph), FOS: Physical sciences},
    publisher   = {arXiv},
    year        = {2023},
}

@Article{Huang2023,
    author      = {Huang, Cheng and Duraisamy, Karthik},
    date        = {2023-01-21},
    title       = {Predictive Reduced Order Modeling of Chaotic Multi-scale Problems Using Adaptively Sampled Projections},
    doi         = {10.48550/ARXIV.2301.09006},
    eprint      = {2301.09006},
    eprintclass = {physics.comp-ph},
    eprinttype  = {arXiv},
    copyright   = {arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license},
    file        = {:http\://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.09006v1:PDF},
    keywords    = {Computational Physics (physics.comp-ph), Fluid Dynamics (physics.flu-dyn), FOS: Physical sciences},
    publisher   = {arXiv},
    year        = {2023},
}

@Article{Lin2023,
    author      = {Lin, Yan and Bao, Jinming and Zhang, Yijin and Li, Jun and Shu, Feng and Hanzo, Lajos},
    date        = {2023-01-26},
    title       = {Privacy-Preserving Joint Edge Association and Power Optimization for the Internet of Vehicles via Federated Multi-Agent Reinforcement Learning},
    doi         = {10.48550/ARXIV.2301.11014},
    eprint      = {2301.11014},
    eprintclass = {cs.LG},
    eprinttype  = {arXiv},
    copyright   = {arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license},
    file        = {:http\://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.11014v1:PDF},
    keywords    = {Machine Learning (cs.LG), Artificial Intelligence (cs.AI), Cryptography and Security (cs.CR), FOS: Computer and information sciences},
    publisher   = {arXiv},
    year        = {2023},
}

@Article{Maudoux2023,
    author       = {Maudoux, Christophe and Boumerdassi, Selma},
    date         = {2023-01-26},
    journaltitle = {IEEE 11th International Conference on Cloud Networking (CloudNet), IEEE ComSoc; Cnam, Nov 2022, Paris, France. pp.277-281},
    title        = {LemonLDAP::NG -- A Full AAA Free Open Source WebSSO Solution},
    doi          = {10.1109/cloudnet55617.2022.9978777},
    eprint       = {2301.11092},
    eprintclass  = {cs.CR},
    eprinttype   = {arXiv},
    booktitle    = {2022 {IEEE} 11th International Conference on Cloud Networking ({CloudNet})},
    copyright    = {arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license},
    file         = {:http\://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.11092v1:PDF},
    keywords     = {Cryptography and Security (cs.CR), Networking and Internet Architecture (cs.NI), FOS: Computer and information sciences},
    month        = {nov},
    publisher    = {{IEEE}},
    year         = {2023},
}

@Article{Williams2023,
    author      = {Williams, Jennifer and Pizzi, Karla and Das, Shuvayanti and Noe, Paul-Gauthier},
    date        = {2023-01-21},
    title       = {New Challenges for Content Privacy in Speech and Audio},
    doi         = {10.21437/spsc.2022-1},
    eprint      = {2301.08925},
    eprintclass = {eess.AS},
    eprinttype  = {arXiv},
    booktitle   = {2nd Symposium on Security and Privacy in Speech Communication},
    copyright   = {arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license},
    file        = {:http\://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.08925v1:PDF},
    keywords    = {Audio and Speech Processing (eess.AS), Cryptography and Security (cs.CR), Sound (cs.SD), FOS: Electrical engineering, electronic engineering, information engineering, FOS: Computer and information sciences},
    month       = {sep},
    publisher   = {{ISCA}},
    year        = {2023},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\title{Test Document}

\author{Test Author}

% The paper headers
\markboth{\textsl{Test}}%
{}
%\markboth{-{}-{}-,~Vol.~-{}-{}-, No.~-{}-{}-, -{}-{}-~-{}-{}-}%
%{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: A Sample Article Using IEEEtran.cls for IEEE Journals}

\IEEEpubid{0000--0000/00\$00.00~\copyright~2023 IEEE}
% Remember, if you use this you must call \IEEEpubidadjcol in the second
% column for its text to clear the IEEEpubid mark.

\maketitle
\nocite{*}

\begin{abstract}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[2-5]

\section{Beginnings}
\IEEEpubidadjcol

\lipsum[6-12]

\printbibliography

\newpage

\vfill

\end{document}
```

And the output (second page) looks like this:
[image: The text overflows in entry (6) in the second column of the bibliography.]
In this example, the problematic bibliography text is in the second column, so it runs off the page. In my article, some of the text was in the first column and ran *over* the other bibliography entries in the second column. The problem also occurs with PdfLaTeX and Biber (the example above uses XeLaTeX only because there is a special character in one of the citations).

**How do I fix this?**

Comment: You're loading the `ulem` package (in the long list of packages in line 14). That package changes the standard behaviour of `\emph` from italics to underlining. This underlining does not line break in `biblatex`-generated bibliographies. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70851/35864.

Comment: The best solution is not to load `ulem`. If you need underlining, load the package as `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}` to stop it from redefining `\emph`.