# How to force Latex to a break a line in Bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies

I have in my bibliography a citation of PHD thesis

[image: It looks like it]

```
@phdthesis{Gowling2023PHD,
   author = "Gowling, Chloe",
    title = "{Observational prospects for gravitational waves from cosmological first order phase transitions at LISA}",

    school = "Sussex U.",
    year = "2023"
}
```

From the picture one can see it clearly sticks outside the margins, how can I force latex to break the line, in order to make it not stick outside the margin?

Comment: Have a look at lua-ul. This allows underlines without preventing line breaks

Comment: Possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9550/why-does-underlined-text-not-get-wrapped-once-it-hits-the-end-of-a-line

Comment: Is the underlining of the title intended? Maybe you are just using package `ulem` (without option `normalem`) and the titles should be emphasized? In this case → https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70851/277964